# Using Linq First Group particular Column value and then Make Avg of values from second column

Tags: c#, linq

I have Datatable having 2 columns URL and ResponseTime.

```
URL             ResponseTime
Login.aspx          2
Login.aspx          3
Login.aspx          4
Login.aspx          5
WelcomePage.aspx    6
WelcomePage.aspx    7
WelcomePage.aspx    8
WelcomePage.aspx    9
LogOut.aspx         10
LogOut.aspx         10
LogOut.aspx         11
LogOut.aspx         11
```

I Want to make Group of it and the make avg of Response Time value for an URL.
Is there any Linq syntax for the same?

```
URL             AvgResponseTime
Login.aspx          3.5
WelcomePage.aspx    7.5
LogOut.aspx         10.5
```

Comment: Please, share what have you tried and how is data represented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("URL")).Select(x => new 
             { 
                 URL = x.Key, 
                 AvgResponseTime = x.Average(y => y.Field<int>("ResponseTime"))
             });
```

Here's a more dynamic solution. It returns the result as a list of dictionaries.

```
dtResponseTimes.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["X_Axis_Categories"].ToString()).Select(x =>
{
    var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    keyValues.Add("URL", x.Key);

    foreach (DataColumn column in dtResponseTimes.Columns)
    {
        if (column.ColumnName.Contains("ResponseTime"))
        {
            keyValues.Add(
                column.ColumnName, 
                x.Average(Y => Convert.ToInt32(Y[column.ColumnName]))
            );
        }
    }

    return keyValues;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but giving *Specified cast is not valid.* error

Comment: @prashanatchaudhari what are the types of the columns in the datatable? It's probably due to the "ResponseTime" column not being of type `int`

Comment: @prashanatchaudhari otherwise try replacing `y.Field<int>("ResponseTime")` with `Convert.ToInt32(y["ResponseTime"])`

Comment: @NicoHaase the code is self-explanatory, that's the reason why none of the other answers have provided any explanation either.

Comment: Sir this works for me for fixed columns URL and ResponseTimes, I would like to ask if we have dynamic columns of ResponseTimes1VU, ResponseTimes5VU etc and Values in it then how we can achieve this?

Comment: what i tried var result = dtResponseTimes.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["X_Axis_Categories"].ToString()).Select(x => new { URL = x.Key, VU5 = x.Average(Y => Convert.ToInt32(Y["ResponseTimes5VU"])), VU50 = x.Average(Y => Convert.ToInt32(Y["ResponseTimes50VU"])) });

Comment: @prashanatchaudhari and what's your issue? That code should work as well. Remember  that you can use column indexes too instead of column names, to make it more dynamic, for example, instead of `Y["ResponseTimes5VY"]`, `Y[1]`

Comment: @Innat3 datatable - ResponseTimes columns can increase so i want that dynamically pic column name and create average of value syntax and return Datatable.

Comment: @prashanatchaudhari I made some adjustments but if that's not enough you should consider opening a new question.

Comment: @Innat3 I will open new question for dynamic column creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy` and `Average` method to get desired result:

```
var result = (
        from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
        group row by new { Col1 = row["url"] } into g
        select new
        {
            Col1 = g.Key.Col1,
            AvgVal1 = g.Average(x => x.Field<decimal>("responseTime")),
        }
```

The whole code:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("responseTime", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("url");            

        AddRow(dt, "Login.aspx", 2);
        AddRow(dt, "Login.aspx", 3);
        AddRow(dt, "Login.aspx", 4);
        AddRow(dt, "Login.aspx", 5);
        AddRow(dt, "WelcomePage.aspx", 6);
        AddRow(dt, "WelcomePage.aspx", 7);
        AddRow(dt, "WelcomePage.aspx", 8);
        AddRow(dt, "WelcomePage.aspx", 9);
        AddRow(dt, "LogOut.aspx", 10);
        AddRow(dt, "LogOut.aspx", 10);
        AddRow(dt, "LogOut.aspx", 11);
        AddRow(dt, "LogOut.aspx", 11);
        var result = (
            from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            group row by new { Col1 = row["url"] } into g
            select new
            {
                Col1 = g.Key.Col1,
                AvgVal1 = g.Average(x => x.Field<decimal>("responseTime")),
            }
        ).ToList();

static void AddRow(DataTable dt, string url, int responseTime)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["url"] = url;
    row["responseTime"] = responseTime;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);            
}
```